# How to Create a Real-Time Color Map in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a real-time colour map. I want to continuously change slightly the RGB values of some elements in the matrix to make up my colour map. I read data from an excel file and a part of my data looks like this
[image]

Then I want to show the colour change in my colour map in one figure like a video. I tried this code:

```
df=pd.read_excel(r"G:\3Y_individualProject\Crop_color_data.xlsx", usecols="C:E")
color_data_2d=np.array(df.iloc[0:101])
color_data_1d=np.reshape(color_data_2d,(300))
color_data=color_data_1d.reshape(5,20,3)

for x in range(5):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(color_data)
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    plt.pause(0.05)
    for i in range(3):
        color_data[0,1,i]=color_data[0,1,i]+0.1
        color_data[1,1,i]=color_data[1,1,i]+0.2
        color_data[2,1,i]=color_data[1,1,i]+0.25
        print(color_data)
```

But it plots many different figures instead of showing them in a figure as I expected. I've also just tried to learn and use matplotlib.animation. I have tried the code below:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import itertools

def changeColor(x):
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(color_data)
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    
    for i in range(3):
        color_data[0,1,i]=color_data[0,1,i]+0.1
        color_data[1,1,i]=color_data[1,1,i]+0.2
        color_data[2,1,i]=color_data[1,1,i]+0.25

results=FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), changeColor, interval=5)

plt.tight_layout()      
plt.show()
```

But with that code, my figure doesn't even display anything. As said I am quite new to matplotlib.animation so can anyone show me how to use matplotlib.animation or any other way to plot a real-time color map in my case, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @Namfield, please provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: @rpanai, I have edited my question to provide my full code for the example of matpotlib.animation. Actually, I just need to add the libraries I used.

Comment: The code is not reproducible as we don't have the data.

Comment: @rpanai, I have added a part of my data. I want to represent the colours of some objects in an area and I want to create a real-time colour map where some of those objects can slowly change colour. My data represents the RGB values of those objects.